# Eclipse Markdown Tables not rendering

Tags: eclipse, markdown

I have tried four different Markdown editors for Eclipse right now, but none of them is able to render tables in the preview; they are always flat.

A simple table like

```
|hans|pans|
|:---|:---|
|1   |2   |
```

renders like

```
|hans|pans| |:---|:---| |1 |2 |
```

I know that the syntax is correct, since it renders fine in any other markdown tool outside eclipse. FluentMark even offers a table editor, which also works fine.

Since I did not find anything useful by searching the internet, I came to the conclusion that the problem might be connected to my local installation.

And since all plugins I tried have the same problem, it might be some common library which is used by all the plugins.

I'm using Centos 7 and Eclipse 2019-09 R (4.13.0). But I have seen the same behavior on many other Linux/Eclipse installations.

Any hint that might help me solve this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Which plug-ins? How would someone reproduce this problem to help you?

Comment: @nitind: I can reproduce it on any colleagues desktop in the office by just installing the latest EE Distribution of Eclipse. The Mylyin WikiText Editor should be default.

What more Information should be provided?

Comment: I don't know that it is a default. Are you sure you're using it?

Comment: @howlger If I know which component to fix I'd do it. Unfortunately I'm busy and paid to write some other OSS. So I do not have the time reviewing all the code that is necessary ... would you?

Comment: @nitind I tried the other plugins because of the table problem. If I choose to open the .md file with WikiText, what other option do I have to verify I'm actually using it?

Comment: Just that, which honestly should have been in the original question. I can't tell from its doc whether it supports tables, though.

Comment: The Markdown editor of the Eclipse EE IDE package is part of [WikiText](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/mylyn.docs). It seems, [tables are supported in e.g. AsciiDoc](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508197) but [not yet in Markdown](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548595) (see also [source code](https://git.eclipse.org/c/mylyn/org.eclipse.mylyn.docs.git/tree/wikitext/core/org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.markdown/src/main/java/org/eclipse/mylyn/wikitext/markdown/internal/MarkdownDocumentBuilder.java)).

Comment: Please note, [tables aren't part of the core Markdown spec](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#tables).

Comment: @howlger thnx so far, I didn't notice that tables are not part of the spec. Also thnx for the code link. I'll keep that in mind for maybe a later opportunity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [Markdown specification](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/), the **correct table syntax** via the so-called [**HTML blocks**](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#html-blocks) is as follows:

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>hans</th><th>pans</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

The Eclipse Markdown editor which is part of [WikiText](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/mylyn.docs) renders this syntax correctly.

In contrast, the [**table syntax you are talking about is a widely used Markdown extension**](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#tables) (e.g. supported by GitHub, Bitbucket, etc.), but **[not supported by the Eclipse WikiText Markdown editor](https://github.com/eclipse-mylyn/org.eclipse.mylyn/issues/364)** yet, maybe because it is not part of the core Markdown specification (see the [source code](https://git.eclipse.org/c/mylyn/org.eclipse.mylyn.docs.git/tree/wikitext/core/org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.markdown/src/main/java/org/eclipse/mylyn/wikitext/markdown/internal/MarkdownDocumentBuilder.java) and for comparison, the [WikiText AsciiDoc editor that supports tables](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508197)).

Comment: As the issue tracker for Mylyn wikitext has been moved around, I see this is the current place, where I've reported a new ticket: https://github.com/eclipse-mylyn/org.eclipse.mylyn/issues/364

Comment: @OlivierBerger Thanks, I updated the bug/issue link. Please consider to provide a pull request with this enhancement. It would be nice if someone would provide a pull request for this enhancement.

Comment: yeah, someone may be brave enough... but not me. As far as I'm concerned, I'm an emacs user and will use the table editor in Emacs' markdown mode, even if this requires switching tools out of Eclipse and back :-/