# Eclipse Markdown Preview Editor brooken?

Tags: eclipse, markdown

Using eclipse: Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0) Build id: 20190614-1200. On Ubuntu 19.10.

I have installed the Eclipse Markdown Editor in eclipse:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/markdown-text-editor#group-screenshots

But seems the preview editor is broken - it cannot render tables:

[image]

I looks fine when I push the README.md to bitbucket:

[image]

So Markdown is correct. Maybe.

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/markdown-text-editor#group-screenshots

is still in alpha state and there are better/more mature markdown editors for eclipse?

**UPDATE:**

Works out of the box in VS Code:

[image]

Maybe not strictly following the markdown specification but I guess 99.99% of users (including me) does not care about that and basically just want same behavior as github/bitbucket.E.g.(unless you want to pay):

http://www.wayneparrott.com/best-markdown-tool-for-eclipse/

So another bullet in the good old eclipse coffin/IDE.

On a side note also tried the *github flavored markdown* plugin for eclipse but for some reason its not compatible with my version of eclipse - yet another example of a problem you would not really expect to have to investigate for a modern IDE:

[image]

so that plugin is too fragile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse Markdown Tables not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050066/eclipse-markdown-tables-not-rendering)

Comment: It depends what processor the extension uses. [The original specification](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) doesn't support tables at all since it was designed for prose, not technical writing.